# In General You Could Do Something?

Tags: modal-verbs

Person A: After listening to a video clip, do you comment with "I like it" or "I liked it"?

Person B: The present tense is probably better. **In general**, though, you **can** use either.

Can I use "could" in place of "can" here? I mean, do we use "could" with "in general" or "generally", if we want to show doubt or sound tentative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use "could" in place of "can" here? I mean, do we use "could"
> with "in general" or "generally", if we want to show doubt or sound
> tentative?

It doesn't make sense to use "generally" with "could" because "could" relates to a specific choice.  General and the specific are antonyms.

Therefore use "can".

Answer (score 1):

> In general, though, you can use either.

> In general, though, you could use either.

Both of these are perfectly valid and natural-sounding. A fluent speaker might well use either sentence. The meaning is essentially identical. "Can"  focuses more on possibility, and "could" more on an expectation that something might occur, but in this usage that difference is not significant.

The comment in another answer that

> It doesn't make sense to use "generally" with "could" because "could" relates to a specific choice.

is in my view not correct. The word "could" does not relate any more to a specific choice than "can does" and "could" may be used to describe a general possibility, and mayn be used together with "generally".

See ["Could," "can," and "would"](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/could-can-and-would) from the *Learner's Dictionary*.

Comment: So *If* person B responded with any of the following: a) You **would generally/usually** hear the second one...b) You **could generally/usually** hear the second one....c) You **might generally/usually** hear the second one....Would that be OK?